# Get current oldid of a Mediawiki-hosted page

Tags: mediawiki-api

In Wikipedia (and other Mediawiki servers), each page has history, and each point in history is identified with its `oldid`.

How to retrieve the current `oldid` (current version) of `http://server/wiki/Article`?

With the [Mediawiki API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php), preferably retrieving only that.
For intergration in a bash script.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of the API?

Comment: @svick: Yes, I even linked to it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `info` operation of the Mediawiki API gives it, among other information:

HTTP request:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&format=xml&titles=Main%20Page
```

HTTP response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <query>
    <pages>
      <page pageid="15580374" ns="0" title="Main Page" contentmodel="wikitext"
        pagelanguage="en" touched="2014-01-21T08:00:12Z" lastrevid="574690625"
        counter="" length="6391" />
    </pages>
  </query>
</api>
```

The part you want is **lastrevid**.